# Generating automatic ID with Prefix

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am setting up a database for employees and I need the employee ID to be incremented and with Prefix like "US0001"

i have tried a code that extracts the last two digits and add 1 to it to get the next Employee ID. But at the eleventh record, it discontinues and says duplicate records cannot be created.

```
    'retrieving the user_id and adding a number to it.
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
    'Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim intCount As Int16 = 0
    'cn.Open()
    Dim cmddr As New OleDbCommand
    cmddr.CommandText = "SELECT user_id FROM tblusers " & _
    "WHERE user_id=(SELECT MAX(user_id) FROM tblusers)"
    cmddr.Connection = cn
    dr = cmddr.ExecuteReader
    dr.Read()
    If dr.HasRows = True Then
        Dim str As String
        str = dr.Item("user_id")
        Dim lst2 As Integer
        lst2 = str.Substring(str.Length - 2)
        txt_user_id.Text = "U0" & lst2 + 1
    Else
        txt_user_id.Text = "U01"
    End If

    dr.Close()
    'cn.Close()
```

I want the employee ID to be generated with prefix and also no duplicates formed

Comment: Print out lst2 right after getting the value. It will tell you what you did wrong. After U09, it would be U010 with your code, is this ok? Also, turn Option Strict On :)

Comment: @the_lotus, it wil generate the U010, but it suppose to be U10.

Comment: `U10` or `US0010`? As your question states that the first ID should be `US0001`.

Comment: Use a normal autonumber and pad it with formatting and the "US" as part of the format. No need to jump through hoops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you can change your SQL statement to simply:

```sql
select max(user_id) as max_id from tblusers
```

There is no need for the subquery within the `where` clause.

And of course change the following corresponding line from:

```vb
str = dr.Item("user_id")
```

To:

```vb
str = dr.Item("max_id")
```

---

Secondly, note that the logic of your code will result in the following numbering sequence:

```
U01
U02
U03
...
U09
U010
U011
...
```

Which means that when the sequence reaches the tenth record, `max(user_id)` will always return `U09` until the sequence reaches `U090`.

To solve this, you will need to pad your user ID with leading zeroes, for example:

```vb
If dr.HasRows Then
    txt_user_id.Text = "US" & Right("000" & (Mid(dr.Item("max_id"), 3) + 1), 4)
Else
    txt_user_id.Text = "US0001"
End If
```

Comment: What about .ExecuteScalar. This doesn't require a reader. Also, it should be pointed out that this needs to be a single user application.

Comment: @mary, what if it is a multiuser application. The User ID will be generated at the time of saving. So it doesn't create duplicates. Or do you have another means for multiuser application?

Comment: I do not see an Insert statement. If a user ask for Max(Id) directly after you do then you will both try to insert a record with the same Id.